# How to fix heartbleed without apt-get upgrading everything?

Tags: nginx, openssl, debian, heartbleed-bug

I ran `apt-get install openssl`

and verified that the new version .1g is installed

```
root@nyc2-04-www:~# apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1g-1
  Candidate: 1.0.1g-2
  Version table:
     1.0.1g-2 0
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.1g-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u6 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u4 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

However, I notice that even though the new openssl is installed, my servers are still vulnerable unless I do a full `apt-get upgrade`

See here:  http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/#www.uat.phantomjscloud.com

How can I avoid doing the full apt-get upgrade, but ensure the new openssl is being used?

FYI I did verify that doing  `apt-get upgrade` will fix heartbleed (i did that in my production server)  But I'm currious as to why updating openssl isn't good enough.

FYI I am using nginx.  I also did `apt-get install nginx` afterwards but that didn't resolve the issue either

UPDATE:  running `openssl version -a` shows that **1.0.1f** is still active, even after reboot.

Comment: Did you stop and restart affected processes?

Comment: yes, though i did that by rebooting the entire system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get install libssl1.0.0` fixes the problem

Comment: if this is the answer to the question (even if it is your own q), please "accept" it. also note that this has nothing todo with programming, and should have been asked on [sf] instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that if it stills says "OpenSSL 1.0.1e" (which is said to be vulnerable) when you run "openssl version -a" after having done the update, you need to look at the build date to verify that the update succeeded. The "built on" field must say a date after April 7, 2014.

Comment: for me it was 1.0.1g,  maybe because i previously did ```apt-get install openssl```